# How to connect input to phone's 3.5mm jack and transmit signal via Bluetooth other than PC (no USB, like a dongle)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, headphone-jack

The local gym has elliptical machines facing a row of TVs.  The machine has a panel with a 3.5mm jack and controls to select the TV audio source and volume through the jack.

I always have my phone and Bluetooth earbuds.  I would like to use my phone's 3.5mm jack to connect via wire to the machine for TV audio and transmit from the phone via Bluetooth to my wireless earbuds.

This would be in place of a dongle, as I don't want to carry extra gear around the gym if I don't have to (I can stuff or wrap a wire) as I can almost promise it would get forgotten and left behind (a wire would keep my phone "tethered" and not as easily overlooked).

Comment: I suppose it would need a special cable to attach the phone's microphone to the headphone output from the TV, and then an app to repeat the microphone sound to the wireless earbuds. Stereo sound would be missing since the phone has only one microphone port.

Comment: Although theoretically possible it's really not doable.